# how to keep padding for image in the ActionBar when Up button is enabled

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to add a padding for both the image displayed in ActionBar and for the one displayed when Up button is enabled (I have a search actionview item which makes the Up button appear).

What I am doing currently:
in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` I am calling:

```
ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(android.R.id.home);
view.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```

This works fine for the image displayed in the ActionBar.

But as soon as I tap the search item and the Up button appears, the image does not have the padding anymore.

Is Up button using a separate image?

Comment: I think you should add the padding to the home/logo drawable itself, not by manipulating the layout padding via code.  In Photoshop you can increase the "Canvas size" to add the transparent pixels on all four sides.

Comment: that's the plan D :) it would be nicer and easier to do this by code instead of having specifications for the image. the image is loaded from a backend and it's setup by customer.